Ask: Azure container app failed to add custom domain
sorry i currently have ACR & container app in my azure account with current domain from azure and now need to add custom subdomain behind cloudflare, as far as i test:

when i tried to add using A record and add into my cloudflare it failed when validate
when test using cname its working to validate but it failed when add "failed to add hostname . Failed to provision revision for container app ''. Error details: The following field(s) are either invalid or missing. Field 'template.revisionsuffix' is invalid with details: 'Invalid value: "updateimage20240906-1": revision with suffix updateimage20240906-1 already exists.';.."
For above cname error when add is it due i need to generate my own cert from cloudflare and add into my azure container app ? as ATM i tested only with managed certificate
If i using cname i cant enabled the proxied of from my cloudflare account if i want to make it works for proxied what should i set as from what i test in my container app the ip not change (after i stop/revision image)

Is there any best practice for this config of container app behind Cloudflare and above error ?
Thank you

Use CNAME with Custom Certificate. Ensure that the proxy feature is correctly configured on Cloudflare, and monitor dynamic IP changes from Azure. Please check- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/custom-domains-certificates

Sorry doest it mean even with cname record in Cloudflare for azure container app its possible to set proxied in Cloudflare side ?  i thought it will only possible for A record. Thanks

it is possible to set CNAME records in Cloudflare as proxied, not just A records. Cloudflare supports both A and CNAME records for proxied traffic. https://developers.cloudflare.com/dns/manage-dns-records/reference/proxied-dns-records/ . I suggest you post this question on the cloudfare community for better clarity

Hi thank you for your advice, i able to add custom domain though but does it mean the application url should be change as well from old one to my custom domain or it should be stick to original from azure ? i notice app url container app still use the original domain url though (azureapps.io)

Yes, once you add a custom domain to your ACA, the application URL can change to reflect your custom domain. However, the original Azure-provided domain (e.g., *.azureapps.io) will still remain accessible. The custom domain is an additional entry point, allowing users to access your app through the domain you configured via cloudflare.

And for your second question, you are correct, you should update any references or configurations (e.g., API endpoints, redirects) to use your custom domain.
Since using Cloudflare, ensure the proxy is enabled for the custom domain, so traffic is routed correctly through Cloudflare.
The original domain (*.azureapps.io) will still function unless explicitly disabled. You can choose whether to exclusively use the custom domain or keep both active for different use cases.

sorry to ask this again, may i know how to switch the domain to exclusively using the new custom domain, i cannot find (google it perhaps i miss) the option in azure container apps setting for switch that though as the endpoint still pointing to azureapps.io while its true i can access the new custom domain but due the config app django i set for csrf and allowed host seems make the cors not working

Did you update the ALLOWED_HOSTS setting in your Django settings.py file to include your custom domain?  and updated CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS to include the full URL of your custom domain? Not working? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/ref/settings/#csrf-trusted-origins

i did though but somehow it still pointing to default Azure domain even though if i test some process submit data failed fetch api call (pointing to default domain check from browser console) but when access the admin django with new domain its working as long as i put in allowed host, i can think something like allowed host of multiple domains (default azure domain and new custom domain) but seems like this is not best solution - and when i notice in azure container apps dashboard ingress endpoint and app url still pointing to default azure domain i thought this can be change please cmiiw

Thank you @Arko, its works now due in the frontend npm vite_api turns out there's variable env which still pointing to default azure url backend and now im thinking to make it works for set in variable container instead on env, i tested its not working if i put in azure container apps of environment variables seems it need to set at prebuild container

It seems like you've identified the core issue where the environment variables used in your frontend (like npm and vite) are still pointing to the default Azure domain.
From your testing, it appears that environment variables set at runtime (within Azure) won’t take effect unless you rebuild the container image with those variables. I recommend setting the API URL (vite_api) to point to the custom domain before the container is created. You can achieve this by using a .env file or build arguments during the build process.
As for your Django setup, it’s perfectly fine to include both the Azure default domain (*.azureapps.io) and your custom domain in the ALLOWED_HOSTS. This allows Django to accept requests coming from both domains. However, to avoid CORS issues, ensure that CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS is updated with your custom domain as well.
Once you’ve updated the environment variables in your frontend to point to the custom domain and ensured that your Django backend is correctly configured with ALLOWED_HOSTS and CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS, your app should work smoothly under the new custom domain

Thanks Arko sorry for late reply, i had created env with value of vite url, im kinda wondering for this npm env vite variable url is it possible to be pass in Azure devops variable i tried to create it through variable pipeline but still not working based on this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops
